# Flash Graph not getting printed using Window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, flash, iframe

I have some flash graphs in an iFrame element (say iFrame_disp). For a business reason we copy the innerHTML of iFrame_disp to a new iFrame element (say iFrame_print).

To print I am using javascript function Window.print() .

But all the plain HTML content gets(other spans, divs) printed but none of the flash graph contents shows up. Though I can see the content in DOM structure under iFrame_print.

Is it a known issue with Flash content ?

Comment: I've never heard of any browser plugin being printable with rest of webpage. Flash Player has it's own print option (Right-click on Flash content).

Comment: See this **[Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843282/printing-a-page-with-embedded-swfs-works-in-ie-but-not-in-chrome)** It seems they can print using Internet Explorer. Also check if the "print preview" has a visual difference between using your Browser's own menu option for printing VS the JScript function `Window.print()`.

Comment: Thanks VC. The problem is with copying the innerHTML as we don't copy the xmlData of window to the new iFrame so the graphs don't get generated again in the new iFrame window. If I print() on the original iFrame, the graphs print fine. Both 'print preview' and actual printout are same.